# Load S3 data into Aurora MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-s3, bulk-load

I'm trying to load the data in S3 into Aurora MySQL instance. I did it using PySpark and the performance of that is at 4 GB per hour.

```
current_df.write.format('jdbc').options(
            url=url,
            driver=jdbc_driver,
            dbtable=table_name,
            user=username,
            password=password).mode("overwrite").save()
```

Added few performance improvements and observed the performance got improved(7 GB per hour), however it's still not that great.

**Parameters Added to the JDBC URL**

```
useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

I tried another approach

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://${s3.bucket}/${filename}' INTO TABLE ${TableName} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

This way it's loading 5 GB per hour into MySQL.

I have close to 2 TB of data needs to load into MySQL instance. Is there any possible way to load the data faster.

Answer (score -1):

Some random thoughts; I hope some will help:

- Increase the allotted IOPS on *both* sides.  (If you can get some metrics, you might be able to decide *which* side needs more.)
- What is `s3://...` -- sounds like reaching into a remote file system?  How remote?
- If it is quite remote, consider zipping and copying the files some closer spot, then unzip (since `LOAD` does not have an unzip option).
- Remote...  Perhaps you are network bandwidth limited?
- Run the `LOADs` in parallel.  How many?  It is hard to say.  Probably the IOPS on one end or the other would be the limiting factor.
- Do you have an 'excessive' number of indexes on the tables?  This could slow down the `LOAD`.  Removing indexes could speed up the `LOAD`, but you would need to re-add the indexes later.  The main point is to get rid of indexes you will not need.
- Having the source files already sorted in `PRIMARY KEY` order will spead up `LOAD` (assuming the target schema already has the PK defined, which it should).  Of course, pre-sorting the files takes time, so there is a tradeoff.